# How to align objects in a constrain angle mode?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, alignment

How to align objects in a constrain angle mode?
a picture is worth a thousand words

[image]

maybe a plugin do the job?

Comment: You can also `Cmd+K` your way into AI's general preferences, where you can adjust the constrain angle. It should be enough if you don't need to change it constantly. Actually, the first thing that came to mind from your example: [What if you make that horizontally first. Then make it into a symbol that you rotate?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/CDD46.gif)

Comment: but the duplicate question didn't answer my question @Scott .. your answer didn't answer how to align objects while I am in constrain angle. ... anyway Joonas had a nice idea I hope there was a script or plugin.